# Share folder with active directory group permissions

Tags: active-directory, debian, samba, share

I have a Debian as a member of our AD (which is a 2k3).

I want to share 2 folders from our Debian. 1 with full access for everyone, the second only readable by group "ADM", and "PROD".

Part of smb.conf:

```
[global]
workgroup = MYDOMAIN
realm = MYDOMAIN.LOCAL
netbios name = SERV-FTP
wins server = "IP serv 2k3"
security = domain

[JUKEBOX] // full access
path = /media/JUKEBOX/JUKEBOX
comment = sharing
writable = yes
browsable = yes
public = yes
read only = no
valid users = @ASYLUM\prod_std
admin users = @ASYLUM\ADM

[SOFTWARE]
comment = Software
path = /media/JUKEBOX/SOFTWARE
valid users = @ASYLUM\prod_adv, @ASYLUM\ADM
writable = yes
read only = no
```

My log :

```
[2013/10/25 09:24:37.316643, 0] smbd/service.c:1055(make_connection_snum) canonicalize_connect_path failed for service SOFTWARE, path /media/JUKEBOX/SOFTWARE
```

And, from my Windows's client, if i want to access on that folder : 
Windows can't access to \serv-ftp\software

Where is the problem ... ?

Thx !

Comment: What is the file system permissions on `/media/JUKEBOX/SOFTWARE`? Connecting users need to be able to read+execute it

Comment: I'm checking that. I need to configure it in /etc/fstab ? With 777 ?

Comment: K, i used mount -t auto /dev/sdd1 /media/JUKEBOX && ls /media/JUKEBOX. I get all privilege (like 777). But, now all people can access over all folders ... I need to set permissions

Comment: at least remove the write permission bit if it's to be read-only

Comment: It's removed ... but i have the same error